# How to delete an unknown number of numpy array indices?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, del

I have a numpy array in which I'd like to delete any zero values in the data. These can occur more than once so I can't use remove(), I can't use pop() because I don't want the repeated value, and I can't use del because the numpy array is immutable. I saw an example online that can be seen below, which would work but (since the data that would be used is dynamic and changing) it doesn't in this case since there's more than more index to eliminate. Basically I need a copy of the same array but an n amount of indices removed.

```
#What was seen online
b = np.delete(a, [2,3,6])

#My current code
for i in range(487):
    if initial[i] == 0:
        newInitial[i] = np.delete(initial,i)
        newSum = np.delete(summary,[0,i])
   
    else:
        pass

for i in range(487):
    if final[i] == 0:]
        newFinal = np.delete(final,i)
        newSum = np.delete(summary,[-1,i])
    
    else:
        pass
    
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(487):
        if middle[i,j] == 0:
            newMid = np.delete(middle,[i,j])
            newSum = np.delete(summary,[i+1,j])
            
        else:
            pass
        
for i in range(487):
    if summary[0,i] == 0:
        newSum = np.delete(summary,[0,i])
        newInitial = np.delete(initial,i)
   
    else:
        pass

for i in range(487):
    if summary[-1,i]:
        newSum = np.delete(summary,[-1,i])
        newFinal = np.delete(final,i)
    
    else:
        pass
    
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(487):
        if summary[i+1,j] == 0:
            newSum = np.delete(summary,[i+1,j])
            newMid = np.delete(middle,[i,j])

    else:
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output? _and I can't use del because the numpy array is immutable._ Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @AMC yes for sure, since the numpy array is of declared size I can’t just “erase” values, as an error would arise saying you can’t delete numpy array elements. Rather you can make a copy array excluding those elements, only I’ve only seen examples where one element is excluded, whereas my script requires n excluded elements.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, couldn't you use a simple mask to select non-zero values?

Comment: @AMC I'm not familiar with masking, would you mind explaining?

Comment: Take a look at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays, it might help clarify things.

Answer (score -2):

maybe if you use the command del

for example:

list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # declarate a numeric list

del list[1]  # delete the element number 1 of the array list

del list[0:3]  # delete all this elements of the interval 0 → 3 of the array (star:end)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But that won't work in my case since it's a numpy array, and I don't know the indices to delete